# delete part of string (word) in tcl

Tags: string, tcl, special-characters

In Tcl I have some variable (string) witch are come from some input text file.
They are too many...
Some thing look like what you are going to faced over :

```
 A1 = LP89slc.AT271300.0
 A2 = LP89slc.AT28742.0
 A3 = LP89slc.AT2-71300.0
 A3 = LP89slc.AT2-0.260-0.085
```

All of them have the same part in the meddle of the string  (`{...}+{.AT2}+{...}`) ==> (`.AT2`)
I want to delete a right part that come next of the (.AT2)
for example :

```
A1 = LP89slc.AT271300.0  ==> LP89slc.AT2
A2 = LP89slc.AT2-71300.0 ==> LP89slc.AT2
```

Also I want to know is there a way that I can delete the last part of a string that come next to the special character like ...At2...
for example : after set unpredictable variable like
{SomeCharecter.At2UndesirablePart} change it to the {SomeCharecter.At2}

The difference between this question and first one is that, in first situation, first part is finite and assignable.
but in second question both part that come in left and right place of {AT2} are unpredictable.

`trim`  `trimright`  `trimleft` commands dont do my job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a regular expression substitution:

```
regsub -all -line {^.*\y(\w+\.AT2).*$} $theString {\1} theString
```

The tricky bits here are the `-line` option (which makes this work when applied to a multi-line string) and the `\y` in the regular expression (which matches at the start or end of a word — it's the start in this case because a `\w` must match next).

Comment: Alternately, `\M` specifically matches the start of a word.

Answer (score 0):

What language do you program in?

VB: i'd do something like

> YourString.replace(".AT2",chr(1)).split(chr(1)(0) & ".AT2"

Java you can use split to
something like

> YourString.split("\.AT2")[0]+'.AT2'

actually it works in most prorgramming languages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But its in tcl language.

Comment: The equivalent Tcl command can be done through `"[lindex [split [string map {.AT2 \0} $text] \0] 0].AT2"` (though your line is missing a closing paren) but it works for one line, as opposed to a whole block of text with multiple lines to replace.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. All of the answer that I heard from you is the best one